# C++ template friend operator overloading

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, friend

What is wrong with my code?

```
template<int E, int F>
class Float
{
 friend Float<E, F> operator+ (const Float<E, F> &lhs, const Float<E, F> &rhs);
};
```

G++ just keeps warning:

`float.h:7: warning: friend declaration ‘Float<E, F> operator+(const Float<E, F>&, const Float<E, F>&)’ declares a non-template function`

`float.h:7: warning: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template has already been declared and add <> after the function name here) -Wno-non-template-friend disables this warning`

I tried to `add <> after the function name here` as mentioned in the warning note, but g++ gives me an error.

I compiled the code with clang++, it was fine, no warning at all.

Comment: You may want to read http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.16

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's just a warning about a tricky aspect of the language. When you declare a `friend` function, it is not a member of the class the declaration is in. You can define it there for convenience, but it actually belongs to the namespace.

Declaring a friend function which is not a template, inside a class template, still declares a non-template function in the namespace. It is neither a member of the class, nor itself a template. However, it is *generated* by the class template.

Generating non-template functions from a template is a bit hazy. For example, you cannot add a declaration for that function outside the `class` block. Therefore you must define it inside the `class` block as well, which makes sense because the class template will generate it.

Another tricky thing about friends is that the declaration inside `class Float {}` does not declare the function in the namespace. You can only find it through argument-dependent meaning overload resolution, i.e. specifying an that an argument has type `Float` (or a reference or pointer). This is not an issue for `operator+`, as it is likely to be overloaded anyway, and it will never be called except for with user-defined types.

For an example of a potential issue, imagine you have a conversion constructor `Float::Float( Bignum const& )`. But `Bignum` does not have `operator+`. (Sorry, contrived example.) You want to rely on `operator+(Float const&, Float const&)` for `Bignum` addition. Now `my_bignum + 3` will not compile because neither operand is a `Float` so it cannot find the `friend` function.

Probably, you have nothing to worry about, as long as the function in question is an `operator`.

Or, you can change the `friend` to be a template as well. In that case, it must be defined *outside* the `class {}` block, and declared before it, instead of needing to be declared and defined *inside*.

```
template<int E, int F> // now this is a template!
Float<E, F> operator+ (const Float<E, F> &lhs, const Float<E, F> &rhs);

template<int E, int F>
class Float
{
  // deduce arguments E and F - this names operator+< E, F >.
 friend Float<E, F> operator+<> (const Float<E, F> &lhs, const Float<E, F> &rhs);
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't you also forward declare the `Float` class before defining the `operator+` template?

Comment: @ValerioFormato Yes; I didn't include it because Zifei must have already done that given the context of his question.

Answer (score 4):

This is quite an old topic but I think the easiest way to declare the operator is to define it inside Float class.

```
template<int E, int F>
class Float
{
public:
    friend Float operator+ (const Float &lhs, const Float &rhs)
    {
        // Whatever you need to do.
    }
};
```

The syntax is easier to write and understand and it will work exactly the same (except that it will be inlined), it will no be a member function.

> MSDN: Friend functions defined inside class declarations are not considered in the scope of the enclosing class; they are in file scope.

Comment: No, in the case of `operator +`, generally the easiest and best way is to implement `operator +=` as a member, and then implement `operator +` as a non-member non-friend in terms of `+=`. This ensures you have both operators defined and they behave consistently.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do exactly as the warnings say:

```
template<int E, int F>
Float<E, F> operator+ (const Float<E, F> &lhs, const Float<E, F> &rhs);

template<int E, int F>
class Float
{
 friend Float<E, F> operator+<> (const Float<E, F> &lhs, const Float<E, F> &rhs);
};
```

This declares a full specialization of the operator template a friend of a specific instance of the class template. In a comment to the question UncleBens has kindly provided [a link to an explanation](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.16) why that is so complicated.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: The friend declaration declares a specific specialization a friend of the class, no?

Comment: Actually, I just tested @sbi's code and it works with my g++.

Comment: @Zifei: This snippet works, but it requires changing the definition of the function. (Sorry, I didn't notice the change to the function's form.)