# Is it a good practice to not to separate function declarations and definitions for templated classes?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, compiler-errors

Generally in non templated classes, we separate the function declarations and definitions into separate files (.h and .cpp)

[1] But the above practice does not seem to work very good with templated classes. Is it advised to write implementations in a separate file and then include it at the bottom of .h file ?

[2] Which of the below scheme is generally advised for templated classes? 
[a] declarations and definition all at once or 
[b]seperated declarations & definitions in the same file

Given the complicated syntax that we have to take care of if we go by choice [b]

Eg.
[a]

```
template <typename T>
class unique_ptr final {
  private:
    T* ptr_;
  public:
    unique_ptr (T* ptr = nullptr) noexcept {
      : ptr_{ ptr } {
    }

    friend bool operator == (const unique_ptr& lhs, const unique_ptr& rhs) {
      return lhs.get() == rhs.get();
    }
};
```

[b]

```
template <typename T>
class unique_ptr final {
  private:
    T* ptr_;
  public:
    unique_ptr (T* ptr = nullptr) noexcept;      
    friend bool operator == (const unique_ptr& lhs, const unique_ptr& rhs);

/*** implementations inside the class after all declarations (I am not sure if this makes the code code any easier to understand)  ***/
  };

/**** Implementations outside the class ***/
/***  Convoluted things needed to make friend functions work ***/
/** like mentioned in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989678/c-template-friend-operator-overloading  ***/
```

Comment: It's a matter of personal preference and team coding guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some functions, like "Koenig operators", cannot be defined outside of the class itself:

```
friend bool operator == (const unique_ptr& lhs, const unique_ptr& rhs) {
  return lhs.get() == rhs.get();
}
```

this is a non-template friend of `unique_ptr<T>`, generated for each template instantiation of `unique_ptr`.  There is no syntax in C++ that permits defining its body outside of `unique_ptr`.  (You can create template friends which are defined outside, but not non-template friends whose arguments are dependent on the template arguments of the template class).

We can get around this by:

```
friend bool operator == (const unique_ptr& lhs, const unique_ptr& rhs) {
  return equal(lhs, rhs);
}
```

and then define `equal` as a template friend of `unique_ptr`.

But even there, you could do:

```
template <typename T>
class unique_ptr final {
  private:
    T* ptr_;
  public:
    unique_ptr (T* ptr = nullptr) noexcept {
      : ptr_{ ptr } {
    }

    friend bool operator == (const unique_ptr& lhs, const unique_ptr& rhs)
#include "unique_ptr_t_operator_equal_function_body.inc"
};
```

if you really wanted to split implementation and interface.

There are no technical barriers to separating implementation and interface into separate `.h` and `.inc` files, placing definitions inline in the template declaration, or placing the definition at the end of the `.h` file.  Using multiple files has a tiny impact on compile times (as the filesystem or a cache of same usually has to be touched on a `#include`), but that isn't usually large compared to other factors.