# Conversion Issues relating to templates (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I am trying to code a template array class and overloading some operators. Part of my code is as follows:

**template.h:**

**main.cpp:**

> C2679 binary '<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Array<int>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

What is causing this error?

Comment: what's the T that you are using to test?

Comment: `int findBigPos(Array<T>* arr, int size, int index)` should probably be `int findBigPos(const Array<T>& arr, int size, int index)`

Answer (score 2):

> What is causing this error?

You are using

```
return this < a;
```

`this` is a pointer while `a` is a reference to an object. It's analgous to comparing an `int*` with an `int`.

```
int a = 10;
int b = 11;
int* p = &b;
if ( p < a ) { ... }
```

That is not right.

That function needs to be implemented differently. You need to compare each item of the arrays and return an appropriate value.

```
template<typename T>
bool Array<T>::operator<(const T& a)
{
   int lowerLength = std::min(this->arrLength, a.arrLengh);
   for ( int i = 0; i < lowerLength; ++i )
   {
      if ( this->myArray[i] != a.myArray[i] )
      {
         return (this->myArray[i] < a.myArray[i]);
      }
   }

   // If we get here, return a value based on which array has more elements.
   return (this->arrLength < a.arrLengh)
}
```

While at it, make the member function a `const` member function.

```
bool Array<T>::operator<(const T& a) const;
```

and change the implementation accordingly.

Comment: @Anonymous That is because the error you are getting has nothing to do with `operator<`.  That is just one of many errors your code has.

Answer (score 0):

In `findBigPos()` (and your other functions in `Driver.cpp`, too), you should be passing `arr` by reference, not by pointer. When `arr` is a pointer, `arr[index]` is the same as `*(arr + index)` - it performs pointer arithmetic to dereference the pointer at a given offset, it does not index into your array at all. That is why the compiler thinks you are comparing `Array<int>` objects, and not calling your `operator[]`.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include "wallet.h"
#include "currency.h"
#include "array.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void recurSelectionSort(Array<T>&, int size, int index);

template<typename T>
int findBigPos(Array<T>&, int size, int index);

int main() {

    //code
}

template<typename T>
void recurSelectionSort(Array<T>& arr, int size, int index) // move the biggest element in arr to index
{
    if (index == size) {
        return;
    }
    else if (index < size) {
        int bigPos = findBigPos(arr, size, index); //position of "biggest" element
        T bigVal = arr[bigPos]; //the value of "biggest" element
        T copy = arr[index]; //copy of wat ever is going to get copy

        arr[index] = bigVal;
        arr[bigPos] = copy;
        recurSelectionSort(arr, size, index + 1);
        cout << arr;
    }
}

template<typename T>
int findBigPos(Array<T>& arr, int size, int index)
{
    if (index == size - 1) {
        return index;
    }
    else
    {
        int bigPos = findBigPos(arr, size, index + 1);
        return arr[bigPos] < arr[index] ? index : bigPos;
    }
}
```

That said, there are some issues with your `Array` class itself, too.

- You are not implementing the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).  Your class is lacking a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator, and in C++11 and later a move constructor and a move assignment operator.
- you don't have a `const` version of your `operator[]` for your `operator<<` to use, since it takes a reference to a `const Array<T>` as input.
- your `operator[]` is not checking for `index < 0`.  And it would be better to `throw` a `std::out_of_range` exception instead of an `int`.  If it throws at all.  Typically, an array's `operator[]` should not perform bounds checking at all.  That is why containers like `std::vector` and `std::string` have a separate `at()` method for handling bounds checking.
- your `operator<` is not implemented correctly at all.  You can't compare a `Array<T>*` pointer to a `const T&` reference.  You probably meant to dereference the `this` pointer before comparing it to `a`, but then that would lead to an endless recursive loop.  What you should do instead is change `const T& a` to `const Array<T> &a` and then compare the *contents* of `this` to the *contents* of `a`.

Try this:

```cpp
#ifndef ARRAY_HEADER
#define ARRAY_HEADER

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
class Array
{
private:
    int arrLength;
    T* myArray;

public:
    Array(int length = 5);
    Array(const Array &a);
    Array(Array &&a);

    virtual ~Array();

    int getLength() const;

    Array& operator=(Array a);

    T& operator[](int index);
    const T& operator[](int index) const;

    bool operator<(const Array &a) const;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &output, const Array &arr)
    {
        int arrSize = arr.getLength();
        for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
            output << arr[i] << " ";
        }
        return output;
    }
};

template<typename T>
Array<T>::Array(int length)
{
    myArray = new T[length];
    arrLength = length;
}

template<typename T>
Array<T>::Array(const Array<T> &a)
{
    myArray = new T[a.arrLength];
    arrLength = a.arrLength;
    for(int i = 0; i < arrLength; ++i)
        myArray[i] = a.myArray[i];
}

template<typename T>
Array<T>::Array(Array<T> &&a)
{
    arrLength = a.arrLength;
    myArray = a.myArray;
    a.myArray = nullptr;
    a.arrLength = 0;
}

template<typename T>
Array<T>::~Array()
{
    delete[] myArray;
}

template<typename T>
int Array<T>::getLength() const
{
    return arrLength;
}

template<typename T>
Array<T>& Array<T>::operator=(Array<T> a)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(myArray, a.myArray);
    swap(arrLength, a.arrLength);
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
T& Array<T>::operator[](int index) {
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= arrLength)) {
        throw std::out_of_range("index is out of range");
    }
    return myArray[index];
}

template<typename T>
const T& Array<T>::operator[](int index) const {
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= arrLength)) {
        throw std::out_of_range("index is out of range");
    }
    return myArray[index];
}

template<typename T>
bool Array<T>::operator<(const Array<T> &a) const
{
    if (arrLength < a.arrLength)
        return true;

    if (arrLength == a.arrLength)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; ++i)
        {
            if (myArray[i] != a.myArray[i])
                return myArray[i] < a.myArray[i];
        }
    }

    return false;
}

#endif
```

Comment: @Anonymous there are numerous questions on StackOverflow related to writing `friend` operators for templated classes. For instance, [C++ template friend operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989678/). The simplest solution in this case would be to move the implementation of `operator<<` into its declaration. I've updated my answer to show that.